# Android emulator slow and graphics blur on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

All my emulations have pixelated text and images like this on retina display. I've tried adjusting numerous setting to no avail. Does anyone know a solution to get it crystal clear?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me try this; go to avd manager --> Emulated Performance Graphics --> Software GLES-2.0

Comment: not working in windows 11, switch to hardware to software in emulated performance